# Comparing dates to range of dates in two dataframes of unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe containing dates in UNIX style, and some values. I have another dataframe containing two UNIX dates and some more values.
For every date in the first dataframe I want to add the values of the second dataframe if the first date falls within (or on) the range of dates in the second dataframe. The dataframes are unequal in length, so I had trouble using np.where. Right now my solution is checking every individual row in the first dataframe in a for loop, but this takes up a lot of time since it contains 1,7 million rows.

An example of what I want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1543818420000, 100],
                    [1543818480000, 200],
                    [1543818540000, 300],
                    [1543821900000, 400]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1543818300000, 1543818599999, 600],
                    [1543821900000, 1543822199999, 700]])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1543818420000, 100, 600],
                    [1543818480000, 200, 600],
                    [1543818540000, 300, 600],
                    [1543821900000, 400, 700]])
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't really shown the problem you are facing, and the code you have written!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using **[`pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html)** might help here:

```
u = df2.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2[0],df2[1],closed='both'))
df3 = df1.assign(New=u.loc[df1[0],2].to_numpy())
```

---

```
print(df3)
               0    1  New
0  1543818420000  100  600
1  1543818480000  200  600
2  1543818540000  300  600
3  1543821900000  400  700
```